# GetDatabase() call takes databaseId greater than 15

Tags: azure, caching, redis

I am using StackExchange.Redis nuget package and accessing Azure Redis Cache. While executing `GetDatabase(dbid)`, i notice that the function executes and returns valid `IDatabase` object event when `dbid>15`.

From documentation I read that `dbid` is by default 16.

What is the allowable range that i can use for `dbid`?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Redis Cache currently only allows up to 16 databases, although we are considering changing it.  You shouldn't use a value > 15 in this API call.  I would guess that SE.Redis will allow the API call to get an IDatabase with id > 15 but if you try to use it to interact with Redis you will see errors.